# Solving an equation involving ArcLength

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I need an efficient way to divide the length of a curve into equal curve length intervals (computational chemistry stuff).

I tried this simple code but it doesn't seem to work and just sits there "running":

```
NS = number of intervals from 0 to 1;
F = [some function];
L = ArcLength[F, {x, 0, 1}];
For[i = 1, i < NS, i++,
 Solve[ArcLength[F, {x, 0, l]/L == i/NS, l]]
```

Perhaps Mathematica is struggling with the combination of differentiation and integration in an equation to solve.

Comment: please provide reproducible code. What is F, exactly?

Comment: The nature of the function doesn't matter for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a simple curve in the plane.

```
γ = t \[Function] (2 + Cos[10 Pi t])/3 {Cos[2 Pi t], Sin[2 Pi t]};
ParametricPlot[γ[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Compute the velocities of the curve.

```
Ns = 130;
tlist = Subdivide[0., 1., Ns 1000];
Δt = tlist[[2]] - tlist[[1]];
v = t \[Function] Evaluate[N@Sqrt[\[Gamma]'[t].\[Gamma]'[t]]];
vlist = v /@ tlist;
```

For each element `t` of `tlist`, we compute the distance of `γ[t]` to `γ[0]` (using [Tai's method](http://care.diabetesjournals.org/content/17/2/152) ;) ) and store the results in `slist`.

```
slist = Join[{0.}, Accumulate[MovingAverage[vlist, 2] Δt]];
```

Now we create a interpolation function that is an approximation to the *inverse* of the function

$$s \colon {[0,1]} \to {[0, \operatorname{Length}(\gamma)]}, \qquad s(t) = \int_0^t |\gamma'(r)| \, \operatorname{d}\! r.$$

```
sinverse = Interpolation[Transpose@{slist, tlist}];
```

This is how it looks:

```
Plot[sinverse[t], {t, slist[[1]], slist[[-1]]}, AxesLabel -> {"s", "t"}]
```

[image]

We use this function to determine the intervals in the $t$-domain:

```
intervals = Partition[sinverse /@ Subdivide[0., slist[[-1]], Ns], 2, 1];
```

And here a test:

```
intervallengths = ArcLength[γ[t], {t, #[[1]], #[[2]]}] & /@ intervals;
L = ArcLength[γ[t], {t, 0., 1.}];
Max[Abs[intervallengths-L/Ns]]
```

> 1.55839*10^-9

If you need it *really* accurate, you can perform several iterations of Newton's method afterwards:

```
method = Method -> {"NIntegrate", 
    PrecisionGoal -> MachinePrecision, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 20
    };
L = ArcLength[γ[t], {t, 0., 1.}, method];
F = x \[Function] ArcLength[γ[t], {t, #[[1]], #[[2]]}, method] & /@ Partition[Join[{0.}, x], 2, 1] - L/Ns;
F' = x \[Function] With[{a = v /@ x},
    SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> a, 
      Band[{2, 1}] -> -Most[a]}, {Length[x], Length[x]}]
    ];

x = FixedPoint[
   # - LinearSolve[F'[#], F[#], Method -> "Banded"] &,
   intervals[[1 ;; -2, 2]]
   ];
intervals = Partition[Join[{0.}, x, {1.}], 2, 1];

intervallengths = ArcLength[γ[t], {t, #[[1]], #[[2]]}, method] & /@ intervals;

Max[Abs[intervallengths - L/Ns]],
```

> 1.12254*10^-15